# Masonry Not Working (but working perfectly in www.jsfiddle.net)

Tags: javascript, jquery-masonry

As the title says, I am implementing the Masonry in certain part of my wordpress website.

You may check it out [here](http://alphaomega.bendaggers.com/) and find the image below:

[image]

In the image above, that's the place I'm trying to implement the masonry.

The codes for masonry in here:

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/66/)**

```js
$(window).load(function(){
 $('.tentofifteen').masonry({
   // options
   itemSelector: '.grid-item',
   columnWidth: 1,
 });
});
```

```css
.grid-item {
    float: left;
}

.grid-superloop-ten {width:319px; min-height:700px;background:#CCC;}
.grid-superloop-eleven {width:220px; min-height:350px; background:#009;}
.grid-superloop-twelve {width:437px; min-height:350px; background:#F36;}
.grid-superloop-thirteen {width:337px; min-height:350px; background:#CC9;}
.grid-superloop-fourteen {width:319px; min-height:350px; background:#0F0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="tentofifteen">
    <section class="grid-superloop-ten grid-item" id="wired-superloop">
    </section>

    <section class="grid-superloop-eleven grid-item" id="wired-superloop">
    </section>

    <section class="grid-superloop-twelve grid-item" id="wired-superloop">
    </section>

    <section class="grid-superloop-thirteen grid-item" id="wired-superloop">
    </section>

    <section class="grid-superloop-fourteen grid-item" id="wired-superloop">
    </section>
</div>
```

It works right?

The problem is, when I start COPYING the same exact codes from [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/66/) to dreamweaver, nothing is happening. What's wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

In your posted code you are loading masonry twice.
On your site, you are loading masonry before jQuery but calling it with a jQuery function so you need to load your scripts like this instead of the way they are currently.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

BTW, you site is loading 2 versions of jQuery, 1.11.3 and 2.1.3. You need to load just one.